# Matrix maths using SVG api

Tags: javascript, html, svg

For my current project i need matrix maths, all the basic stuff for 2d transformations. I know that there are frameworks like sylvester and so on, but I also found all the functionality I need in the SVG DOM api. So there is an SVGMatrix, a SVGPoint, a SVGRect and so on.

So here is my question:
If I create an memory-SVG, just for the purpose of being the factory for Matrices, Points and Rects, does this provide me with performance advantages? Can I use an SVGMatrix created with the memory-svg in the context of a different SVG (i.e. applying it to elements transform)?

Greetings philipp

Comment: would be nice if one points out the stupid parts of the question when down-voting it.

Comment: I'm also interested on this. Have you done any tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I create an memory-SVG, just for the purpose of being the 
>   factory for Matrices, Points and Rects, does this provide 
>   me with performance advantages?

Coordinate transformations using SVG engine are faster than manual multiplication in Javascript loops, especially when there are thousands of points to transform. So using transformations whenever possible instead of recalculation of coordinates in Javascript is a definite advantage you can easily benchmark. Also DOM manipulations like changes of `path` `d` attribute are slow as turtle.

> Can I use an SVGMatrix created with the memory-svg in 
>   the context of a different SVG (i.e. applying it to elements transform)?

Yes you can, I do that ten times before lunch every day. `SVGMatrix` objects are free-floating and not attached to their factory `SVGSVGElement` (which is itself so called detached DOM object) in any way.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks a lot, the gives more confidence for my new svg project which will start today ;)